# cusp point of a curve

Tags: derivatives, curves, computer-algebra-systems

I use a computer algebra to plot a function $f(x,y)$ and notice the existence of a cusp point. See figure below.

[image: The curve $f(x,y) = 0$]

Now, I want to determine the exact values $x$ and $y$ of the cusp point. I compute the derivative and solve of $y$ as an expression of $x$, then check the value of $x$ for which the derivative is infinity. Is this approach correct?

Below are the expression of $f(x,y)$, derivative of $f$ and solution of $y$. However, $x = 15$ as the x-coordinate of the cusp point does not make sense.

$$\begin{align}
f(x,y) &= -24 x^3+x^2 y^2-16 x^2 y+172 x^2-30 x y^2+264 x y-354 x+y^4-24 y^3+174 y^2-872 y+225\\
\frac{\delta~f(x,y)}{dx} 
&= -72 x^2+2 x y^2-32 x y+344 x-30 y^2+264 y-354
\end{align}$$

Solving $y$ in $\frac{\delta~f(x,y)}{dx}$ gives 
$\left\{y\to \frac{-3 \sqrt{4 x^3-72 x^2+189 x+189}+8 x-66}{x-15}\right\},\left\{y\to \frac{3 \sqrt{4 x^3-72 x^2+189 x+189}+8 x-66}{x-15}\right\}$.

Comment: It’s a strange plot for the given function.

Comment: You are right. My bad. I copied the wrong function. Sorry.

Comment: to obtain dy/dx you can’t use partial derivatives

Comment: Not sure what you are going but the cusp point are located at the point where $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} = 0$.

Comment: Thank you! This was the right answer --> $\frac{\delta~f(x,y)}{\delta x}=\frac{\delta~f(x,y)}{\delta y}=0$. Any further explanation on why it works would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @Fad The key is [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem). On those points when $\nabla f(x,y) \ne 0$, the level set $f(x,y) = $ constant will locally look like a line and cannot be the cusp point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  achille hui commented, you need to solve for $(x,y)$
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} = 0$$ For simplicity, let us write
$$F(x,y)=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=-72 x^2+2 x y^2-32 x y+344 x-30 y^2+264 y-354$$
$$G(x,y)=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=2 x^2 y-16 x^2-60 x y+264 x+4 y^3-72 y^2+348 y-872$$ and use Newton-Raphson with $x_0=4$, $y_0=1$ taken from the graph.

Using bilinearization, we have
$$0=F(x_0,y_0)+(x-x_0)\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}+(y-y_0)\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}$$
$$0=G(x_0,y_0)+(x-x_0)\frac{\partial G(x,y)}{\partial x}+(y-y_0)\frac{\partial G(x,y)}{\partial y}$$ where the partial derivatives are computed at $(x_0,y_0)$

This should give as first iterates
$$x_1\approx 3.98788 \qquad y_1\approx 1.13939$$
$$x_2\approx 4.00598 \qquad y_2\approx 1.19940$$
$$x_3\approx 4.01485 \qquad y_3\approx 1.22965$$
$$x_4\approx 4.01930 \qquad y_4\approx 1.24482$$ Continuing iterations, you would converge to
$$x_\infty\approx 4.02375 \qquad y_\infty\approx 1.26001$$

**Edit after  achille hui's comment**

$F(x,y)$ being a quadratic in $x$
$$F(x,y)=0 \implies x_\pm=\frac{1}{72} \left(y^2-16y+172\pm\sqrt{y^4-32 y^3-1560 y^2+13504 y+4096}\right)$$ Plugging this in $G(x,y)$, did not get anything with $x_-$. However, using $x+$, we end with
$$y^5-40 y^4+3880 y^3-63440 y^2+174056 y-447488$$ $${(y^3-24 y^2-780 y+3376) }\,\sqrt{y^4-32 y^3-1560 y^2+13504 y+4096 }=0$$ Then
$$\frac{ y^5-40 y^4+3880 y^3-63440 y^2+174056 y-447488} {y^3-24 y^2-780 y+3376}+ \sqrt{y^4-32 y^3-1560 y^2+13504 y+4096 }=0$$ which, after squaring, leads to
$$\left(y^3-24 y^2+435 y-512\right)^2\, \, (2 y^2-20 y+113)=0$$ The quadratic factor does not show real roots. So, we are left with$$y^3-24 y^2+435 y-512=0$$ which shows one real root as given by achille hui in his comment. Back to $x_+$, the result !

Comment: After a ton of algebra, I get a surprising simple closed form for the cusp: $$(x_\infty,y_\infty) = \left(\frac{9^{4/3}+9^{3/2}-15}{2},(9^{1/3}-1)^3\right) \approx (4.023751559194681,1.260005336389037)$$
matching your numerical result. I wonder why the expression is so simple.

Comment: @achillehui. Amazing ! I suppose that *ton* stands for *megatons*. Cheers.

Comment: @achillehui. Hoping that you don't mind, I wrote the steps ! If you mind, I shall delete that part of my answer. Cheers.

Comment: I don't mind, I derive that using a completely different method. By the way, I have a typo in my previous comment, $x_\infty$ should be $\frac{9^{4/3} + 9^{\color{red}{2/3}} - 15}{2}$.

Comment: @achillehui. Thanks ! In fact I did not simplify (I am too lazy) $y=8-9 \sqrt[3]{3}+3\ 3^{2/3}$ and $x=\frac{3}{2} \left(-5+\sqrt[3]{3}+3\ 3^{2/3}\right)$

Comment: ClaudeLeibovici and @achillehui Thanks a lot. Yes, with the assistance computer algebra system, I got the same solutions in algebraic forms   $x\to \frac{3}{2} \left(-5+\sqrt[3]{3}+3\ 3^{2/3}\right),y\to 8-9 \sqrt[3]{3}+3\ 3^{2/3}$